# Avoiding PATH variable conflicts when syncing dotfiles?

Tags: bash, unix, dotfiles

I've started using version control and syncing on my various dotfiles using the extremely handy [GNU Stow](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/) thanks to a recommendation on here.

However, I am not sure how to properly stow my .bashrc for syncing across computers, as it contains machine-specific PATH lines that I would obviously not want to sync. Is there a proper way to handle these types of machine-specific lines while syncing dotfiles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Machine-specific settings should be isolated to a separate file which can be sourced from `.bashrc`. So your `.bashrc` might contain a line like

```
[[ -f .bashrc.local ]] && . .bashrc.local
```

Then anything that is specific to a local machine, rather than intended to be shared across machines, would be put in `.bashrc.local` instead. Only `.bashrc` gets synced.

This does present difficulties if you don't want to isolate all machine-specific settings to one point in your shared `.bashrc` file. The alternative is to fill your shared `.bashrc` file with conditional code like

```
case $HOST in
 machineA )  do-this ;;
 machineB )  do-that ;;
 * ) default-behavior ;;
esac
```

which takes the current value of `$HOST` into consideration.

Comment: I love your answer. Very simple. I will wait a bit and most likely select this as top answer.

Thank you!